# Bluetooth communication delayed?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I'm working on an app that would find a specific bluetooth device and connect to it. The thing is, that it takes literally forever for it to detect/discover any visible nearby device.

I've also tried many other ways to detect visible devices, but then again, it took it forever to discover the devices...so I'm assuming it's my phone, since my MiBand(a bluetooth bracelet..) alarm clock rang at 6:50 AM instead of 6:30 this morning...

I haven't tried this on any other phone since i don't have just one..

I even tried to restart the phone or turn bluetooth on and off many times. Didn't help.

I just found out about the delay yesterday, since that's when I started programming the app. And in case you're curious, yes, I did add all permissions to the manifest file.

***but still.. the question is.. what could be causing this and how do I fix it(in case I can)?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what I did to fix this was very simple. I unscrewed the lid from the main circuit board and since it was dusty as hell, i cleaned it a little bit..

Works now... :D